# Storing relationship path between friends[nodes] from neo4j and updating it in future

Tags: facebook, algorithm, indexing, relationship, neo4j

I am developing an application in which i need to show the relationship path between the two person.

In my application ,I have user's Facebook,twitter,linked In and other social network account data .I have my user friends/followes/connections profile.
And from my application user searches for the a friend[or a friends'friends of random person] .In my neo4j ,i am searching for my user's 1 degree contacts [friends],then in friend list of my friends and [2nd degree],same search with 2nd degree friends[3rd degree] .and at last the result collection of searched person names will be shown with connection path[in between friends]

**Example :searching for Mark Nevil
Results :with my algorithm**

**Path 1**
*Me---->my "MY FB" friend [Name it B]----->B's Linked In friend [C] ----->Mark Nevil as [C]'s Twitter friend.*

and I am having such paths from me-->Mark Nevil.
So for future i need to store such paths somewhere[might be in MongoDB or pls suggest a good one].and want to update these paths when friends are being added in DB

this search goes libe on DB when user query .but this takes time and the same search paths to be calculated again and again.

Please suggest good way of storing the path or any algorithm to do such process.

Comment: @Michael Hunger : can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a shortest path search, or all paths, or what is it? Also how long time does it take? How much of your graph fits in memory?

Comment: thanks for fast reply....this is not shortest path search.Its "All Paths".As my application needed to show all paths between two friends Or user[A] and the searched person. first I am Listing [Showing] all results for name in ordered by degree[1st,2nd..upto 4th] then when user clicks on a person link at that time i am showing the available paths between them.[In path the showing persons between them ] .One path in one row showing different relation path

Comment: AllPaths is slow because it's single-directional... however if you download the latest snapshot or await Neo4j 1.8.M04 AllPaths is bidirectional, which means it's way faster... probably fast enough to not need to store the paths separately. In my test it was 100 times faster for my test social graph. Try it out!

Comment: Great. You can also try "All simple paths", see definition in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28graph_theory%29 if you don't allow any node to occur more than once in a path. That should also boost performance a little.

Comment: hi .. i am just putting an relation ship between two node and not making graph directed .but when a user search for person i need got for that searched user again and again with paths [might be as old as OR updated -becoz new paths might be available when new friends are in graph.]so any other idea?

Comment: That's fine, all simple paths will return multiple paths with possibly the same nodes occuring, but within each path any one node cannot occur more than once. Well, anyways I think whether all paths or all simple paths the new neo4j version snapshot (or upcoming 1.8.M04) will prove much faster.

Comment: And if it's fast enough, it may actually not be much slower than retrieving "cached" paths stored somewhere else. Plus you don't have to worry about cache invalidation.